# Log y-axis plot on Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot in log scale with Python and I would like to rearrange the y-axis values by putting 10^-1 and then all the values, instead of what I get:[image]

where the 10^-1 repeats for all values. I need it to shrink a bit the plot.

Many thanks for your help! (and sorry it this has been already solved)

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy.interpolate import griddata, UnivariateSpline
from matplotlib.pyplot import * # plotting library
import math

plt.rcParams.update({
    'text.usetex': True,
    'font.family':'serif',
    'mathtext.fontset' : 'cm',
    'mathtext.rm': 'serif',
    'font.weight': 'normal',
    'axes.labelweight': 'normal',
    'axes.linewidth': 1.5,
    'xtick.major.width': 1.5,
    'xtick.major.size': 10.0,
    'xtick.minor.size': 5.0,
    'ytick.major.width': 1.5,
    'ytick.major.size': 10.0,
    'ytick.minor.size': 5.0,
    'font.size': 30})
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 20})

from matplotlib.pyplot import * # plotting library
import pylab
from matplotlib import ticker
from mpmath import mp
import mpmath

Lx_array=[200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380]

fc[0]= [0.12157595414600386, 0.12041770132162587, 0.12047596487921948, 0.12052880984177164, 0.12057638017580277, 0.12061976850950093, 0.12065915948174381, 0.12069532559157949, 0.12072842279963499,0.12140365733314845]
xfitplot[0]= [200.0, 380.0] #range of L_x
yfitplot[0] = [0.12048675725819148, 0.00041285587251701833] #parameters fit


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10.0,8.0))
subplot(221)
ax=matplotlib.pyplot.gca()

#---------
errorbar(Lx_array,fc[0],fmt='s',ms=10,label=r"$a)$")
plot([Lx_array[0],Lx_array[-1]],[yfitplot[0][0]*Lx_array[0]**yfitplot[0][1], yfitplot[0][0]*Lx_array[-1]**yfitplot[0][1]],'r--',lw=4)
for axis in ['top','bottom','left','right']:
    ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)
#ax.tick_params('both', length=8, width=1.5, which='major', pad=10)
#ax.tick_params('both', length=4, width=1.5, which='minor', pad=10)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.tick_params(direction='in')
ax.tick_params(direction='in',which='minor')
ylabel(r'$f_c$',fontsize=30)
xticks(size=25)
yticks(size=25)
plt.legend(loc='upper right',fontsize=20)
#plt.tight_layout()
```

Comment: please share what you are doing to create the plot. It is hard to help you without  knowing what exactly you have done to create the plot.

Comment: you're right, just edited the question. thanks!

Comment: `Lx_array` is not defined in the sample code. Also, you could think of a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your problem.

Comment: oops sorry again, now should be fine. thanks for the reference.

Comment: When your y-values are so close together, a linear plot would be much clearer.

Comment: @JohanC I generally would agree, but sometimes folks are looking for power laws, so log-log makes more sense...

Comment: @JohanC you are absolutely right, but the other subplots are all (nice) power laws so this one has to adapt, somehow :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a scalar formatter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

x = [200,220,240,260,280,300,320,340,360,380]
fc = [0.12157595414600386, 0.12041770132162587, 0.12047596487921948, 0.12052880984177164, 0.12057638017580277,
      0.12061976850950093, 0.12065915948174381, 0.12069532559157949, 0.12072842279963499,0.12140365733314845]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5.0, 4.0), layout='constrained')
ax = axs[0, 0]

ax.loglog(x, fc, 's')
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')

ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(mticker.ScalarFormatter())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't put the other 3 plots, but they are all linear in log-log scale (also the y axis label). The one I put here is the only one looking "ugly".

Comment: Not clear what you are asking for here.  The yscale above is logarithmic, it's just such a small range that you can't tell.

Comment: The problem is the label of the y-axis. In order to be in harmony with the other three subplots, I would like to regroup the 10^-1, say on top of the y axis, and then leave the values where they are. In my case, I need the 10^-1 to be there in that notation because it gives a easier access to the order of magnitude.

Comment: a scalar formatter would not be nice for the other subplots where I have 10^-3 values.

Comment: Matplotlib tick Formatters are extremely flexible, and you can even just pass a function in.   If you don't like the defaults, you will need to customize manually: you can start here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/ticks/tick-formatters.html